# how do I achieve concurrency in scrapy when there is only one start url?

Tags: scrapy

I have a situation where I need to send 20 requests per second to the web server with scrapy. I have a product listing page URL which I am passing to the spider at the start to self.start_urls and there are so many product URLs that I get from that listing page that I need to scrape but it is sending requests to all those product URLs sequentially. how can I make it concurrent?

**Spider code Logic**

```
class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self, country=None, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls.append(url[country][category])

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            request = Request(
                url=url,
                headers=self.default_headers,
                callback=self.parse, 
                cookies=self.cookies,
                cb_kwargs=dict(link= url, asin= self.asin),
            )
            yield request
    
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        products = response.xpath('//link')
        for product in products:
            yield Request(
                url=url,
                headers=self.default_headers,
                callback=self.product_parse, 
                cookies=self.cookies,
                cb_kwargs=dict(link= url, asin= self.asin),
            )

    def product_parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # get all product details
        yield item
```

Comment: You can increase `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` in the settings

Comment: @SuperUser I have done it but it only sends concurrent requests to the URLs in the start_urls list not the other requests inside the parse function

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the code below, you can add `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` in the custom settings for this particular spider locally to enable concurrency requests. Spiders can define their own settings that will take precedence and override the project ones.To read more `Setting per Spider`, refer [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider)

```
 class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'webspider'

    custom_settings = {
     'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' = 32
     }

    def __init__(self, country=None, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls.append(url[country][category])

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            request = Request(
                url=url,
                headers=self.default_headers,
                callback=self.parse, 
                cookies=self.cookies,
                cb_kwargs=dict(link= url, asin= self.asin),
            )
            yield request
```

There are many additional settings that you can use instead of, or together with CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` – Sets the number of concurrent requests per IP address .

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` – Defines the number of concurrent requests allowed for each domain.

`MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN` – Sets a maximum limit on the number of concurrent requests allowed for a domain.